# indexof char in char array returns -1 even that char exists

Tags: java

can any one explain why this code fragment evaluates to -1?

i except it to be 0 as it is the index of '1'

`Arrays.asList("1234".toCharArray()).indexOf((char)'1');`

I also tried:

`Arrays.asList("1234".toCharArray()).indexOf('1');`

`Arrays.asList("1234".toCharArray()).indexOf(49);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do `"1234".indexOf('1')`. No need to convert to an array and then to a List.

The reason your attempts don't work in that when you call Arrays.toList on an array of primitives (`char[]` in your case), it produced a List whose single element is the array itself, so the List doesn't contain '1'.

Comment: yes but, this is just a fragment, in the full code I have a char array that i want to know the index of a char in it...

Comment: @NahumLitvin If you had a `Character` array instead of a `char` array, `Arrays.asList(arr).indexOf('1')` would have worked. You can either convert your char array to Character array, or you can iterate over the array and find the index of the character.

Comment: @Eran: Doh! Of course it does. I was surprised not to find an `Arrays.indexOf(char[],char)`.

Comment: ok the new fixed fragment is:
new String("1234".toCharArray()).indexOf('2');
new String(new char[]{'1','2','3','4'}).indexOf('2');

Java is wierd...